# Is it possible to read a value from an alternate column in a CSV file for the NaN values in a primary column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Suppose I have a CSV file with two columns as shown below:

```
A    B  
1.4  2.4  
3.5  6.2
NaN  4.5  
NaN  2.1
```

A is the primary column which I will use in my analysis by reading it in this way

```
data = pd.read_csv('dat120.csv')
points = data['A']
```

But unfortunately, in some cases, the value of A is NaN as shown above. Here, I want to read the corresponding values in B column in place of A, if A is  NaN. Is it possbile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want replace `NaN`s by next columns use back filling missing values per per rows:

```
df = data.bfill(axis=1)
```

If need replace missing values in `A` by non missing values of `B` use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
data['A'] = data['A'].fillna(data['B'])
```

Difference is possible see if more columns:

```
print (data)
     A    B    C
0  1.4  2.4  NaN
1  3.5  6.2  5.0
2  NaN  4.5  2.0
3  NaN  2.1  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  4.1

df = data.bfill(axis=1)
print (df)
     A    B    C
0  1.4  2.4  NaN
1  3.5  6.2  5.0
2  4.5  4.5  2.0
3  2.1  2.1  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  4.1  4.1  4.1
```

---

```
data['A'] = data['A'].fillna(data['B'])
print (data)
     A    B    C
0  1.4  2.4  NaN
1  3.5  6.2  5.0
2  4.5  4.5  2.0
3  2.1  2.1  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  4.1
```